# Passing query variables to JavaScript to load - is JavaScript on the backend of these APIs?

Tags: javascript, api, flattr

I've been looking at the API for Flattr, http://flattr.com/support/integrate/js , which has a cool way of accepting query variables for their JavaScript to load.

My question is, do most APIs use something other than JavaScript to accept these different variables for their services? EG:
Ruby on Rails
PHP
Python

Then these are parsed by the respective language and returned as outputted JavaScript to the requesting website?

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Javascript itself is totally capable of reading how it's embedded to the HTML it belongs to, by reading document.getElementsByTagName("script") and further parse/match their src attributes. Therefore, it's not a problem at all for it to further parse the query variables attached at the end, and dynamically (all in javascript, client side) load components within.

Any javascript libraries that allow you to pack the whole thing and deploy to your own web server should take this approach, since there's no server to handle the request anyways.

On the other hand, javascript libraries that are hosted on other sites that allow you to use (like YUI) MAY take the server approach like you mentioned.

Comment: I was thinking more along the lines of a server side language would only send out the JS library components specifically needed by the query to reduce load time. 

However there are some nice advantages of calling queries on the page itself to also only load the sections you want.

Answer (score 1):

In my personal experience, projects that I have worked on have used server side languages to deal with get params.
So a request might be /myjavascript.js?id=123123  The server side language would create the correct javascript for that request.

Keeping everything on the server side has the advantage of not allowing the user to see what is going on.  If this isn't a problem for you, javascript is more than capable of handling different params.

Answer (score 1):

In my experience it's fairly common that widgets embedded into others' sites gets their parameters by parsing them from their script tags. It makes the widget script static and self-contained and thus easier to distribute through eg. a fast CDN. Performance is important when you're going to convince someone else to add your javascript to their site as poor performance from the widget can make the entire site appear sluggish.

A better place to specify the parameters than query parameters would however be to specify them in the URL:s hash-part as that part isn't included when caches are checked and thus the script would have to be downloaded fewer times - which of course is good for performance, especially if the parameters might shift a lot.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the CDN aspect.